# JQuery mobile returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying

```js
$(function() {
  convertPrice = function() {
    var myAnswer, myVal, myRate;
    myVal = $('#slider1').val();
    myRate = $('#rate').val();
    myVal = parseFloat(myVal); // convert string  type 
    myAnswer = myVal * myRate;
    $('#Answer').val(myAnswer);

  }

  $("#convertButton").click(convertPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">

  <label for="R">Cost Per Person:</label>
  <input type="text" value="$990" name="rate" id="rate" readonly />
</div>
<label for="slider">Number of People Going?:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider1" value="1" min="1" max="30" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Convert" id="convertButton" />

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="theAnswer">Results:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textInput" id="Answer" value="" readonly />
</div>
```

So when I click the button, it just returns as NaN? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rate input box you have specified $ in value tag. So it is giving NaN value. Change that line of code to

$

Then it will work for sure

Comment: THANK YOU so much! It is always something so small that I miss.

Answer (score 0):

## Use this, but is much better remove "$"

```js
$(function() {
  convertPrice = function() {
    var myAnswer, myVal, myRate;
    myVal = $('#slider1').val();
    myRate = $('#rate').val();
    myRate = myRate.replace("$","");
    myVal = parseFloat(myVal); // convert string  type 
    myAnswer = myVal * myRate;
    $('#Answer').val(myAnswer);

  }

  $("#convertButton").click(convertPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">

  <label for="R">Cost Per Person:</label>
  <input type="text" value="$990" name="rate" id="rate" readonly />
</div>
<label for="slider">Number of People Going?:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider1" value="1" min="1" max="30" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Convert" id="convertButton" />

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="theAnswer">Results:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textInput" id="Answer" value="" readonly />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the earlier answer the $ sign is the issue.Yoo can remove that $ sign it will work.Still if you want to keep that sign then using `regex` you can remove that sign while doing calculation

```
var myAnswer, myVal, myRate;
myVal = $('#slider1').val();
myRate =  $('#rate').val();
myVal = parseFloat(myVal); // convert string  type 
myRate = parseFloat(myRate.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g, "")); // here before convserting we need to use regex to replace $ with ""
myAnswer = myVal * myRate;
$('#Answer').val(myAnswer);
```